# How to negate the following statement

Tags: logic

I am asking how to negate the following statement:

For any positive $k$ there exists a number $N₀$ such that, for all $m≥N₀$, there exists a solution in positive integers to the equation:
$$k/m=1/x+1/y+1/z$$

Comment: The rules for negating quantifiers are : $\lnot \forall \equiv \exists \lnot$ and $\lnot \exists \equiv \forall \lnot$. Thus, the negation of "For any positive k there exists a number N₀ such that, ..." will be "There exists a positive $k_0$ such that for any number $N$ not ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a positive integer $k$  such that for any $N_0$ there exists $m \geq N_0$ with $\frac k m \neq \frac 1 x+\frac 1 y+\frac 1 z$ for any choice of positive integers $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a positive $k$ such that for any $N_{0}$ there exist $m≥N_{0}$ such that does not exists positive integer solution to the equation